# How do I restart a batch program using an input?

Tags: batch-file

```
:START
if restartprogram= "RESTART" GOTO START

else if restartprogram= "NO" echo The program will now end when any key is pressed.

pause
```

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?`. This will show you the proper syntax for doing string comparisons and the proper usage for an `IF ELSE` clause.

Comment: Thanks but I am still confused, I am relatively new to batch coding and I still can't figure out why my program doesn't work.

Comment: Update your question with what you learned about the syntax of the `IF` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several notes:

- The syntax for reading the value of batch variables is `%VAR%`, where `VAR` is the variable name. So for a variable named `restartprogram`, `%restartprogram%` will be interpreted as the value of that variable. The syntax for assigning into a variable is: `set restartprogram=VALUE`.
- First, you'd want to read a value into your variable. For reading a value from the standard input (keyboard) into a variable, use the `SET` command: `set /p restartprogram=`.
- Using the `IF` command, you want to check the variable for equality to RESTART. To check for equality, you should use the `==` operator: `if %restartprogram%==RESTART` (as opposed to a single `=`, which is used for assigning a value into a variable).

Putting everything together:

```
:START
set /p restartprogram=
if %restartprogram%==RESTART GOTO START
if %restartprogram%==NO echo The program will now end when any key is pressed.
pause
```

You'd probably want to go through one of the many batch tutorials out there, such as [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm).

Happy coding!